# Help With Logarithmic Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

Could anyone point me in the direction of an algebraic approach to solving the following: $$\frac{2 -\ln{x}}{x \ln^3{x}} = e$$
I have plotted them and can see a solution around $x\approx1.9$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only approximate solution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Is there a way to see OP equation has no closed form solution? [Didn't see how on the wiki page you cite.]

Comment: So because the variable I am trying to solve for appears in several transcendental functions, and the equation cannot be reduced such that the variable only appears in a single one, we have no closed form solution. This is how I understood the wiki page explanation...

Comment: @coffeemath. I gave only a comment(my opinion) not a answer for problem.

Comment: @JamesIzzard. Maybe in near future 
mathematical genius solved a problem and express solution by known special function.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I await with eager anticipation! In the meantime, I think your suggestion makes sense. For my problem, I only needed to know if the solution was positive or negative, so the approximate solution was satisfactory.